# $f(x)=-8e^{-0.6x}+e^{-0.4x}$. Determine maximum concentration of the drug, and the value of it assuming the experiment runs for 12 hours

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, derived-functors

A person is being tested against a certain drug, and has been injected with it. The drug blood concentration, measured in mg/l, is modeled by the function

$f(x)=-8e^{-0.6x}+e^{-0.4x}$

Here, the variable $x$ measures the time in hours. Determine when does the person have the maximum concentration of the drug in the blood torrent, and the value of it assuming the experiment runs for 12 hours

Can anyone Help me complete this is very confusing. I'm not sure what formula to follow and this question is all over the place

Comment: Differentiate and find Local maxima of the function

Comment: Actually this function is a strictly increasing function in the given time interval

Comment: Could you check your function? $f(0)=-7$ which does not make any sense as a concentration in mg/l.

Answer (score 0):

At your behest @Rquin, I will elaborate

$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx} (-0.8 e^{-0.6x})$$+\frac{d}{dx} ( e^{-0.4x})$

$f'(x)= -0.8 \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-0.6x})+ \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-0.4x})$

$f'(x)= (-0.8)(-0.6)(e^{-0.6x})+ (-0.4)(e^{-0.4x})$

For maxima and minima put f'(x)=0

we get, $(-0.8)(-0.6)(e^{-0.6x})+ (-0.4)(e^{-0.4x})=0$

You will get x=5ln12 which is 12.42

and f'(x)>0 when x $\le12$

So, f(x) will have its maximum value at x=12

f(12)=0.00225706

Comment: so you didn’t need to use a formula? i thought we would have to use the chain rule

Comment: We will get f'(x) using the chain rule

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: When we differentiate function f(x) we use chain rule i.e. derivative of $y=e^{ax}$ will be $$ \frac {dy}{dx}=a.e^ax$$

Comment: @Rquinn All you need to is understand chain rule and then use maxima and minima https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-differentiation-2-new/ab-3-1a/v/chain-rule-introduction

Comment: this is how i did it a little while ago with the chain rule 0=4.8$e^{-0.6x}$ -3.2$e^{-0.4x}$x

-3.2$e^{-0.4x}$ = 4.8$e^{-0.6x}$

-0.4x in 3.2e = -0.6xln4.8e

$\frac{3.2}{4.8}$ = $e^{-0.6x}$/ $e^{-0.4x}$

1.5 = $e^{-0.2x}$
ln 1.5 = -0.2x

ln 1.5/-0.2 = x

x = -2.027

Comment: well,it should be $0=4.8e^{-0.6x}-  0.4e^{-0.4x}.$ I think you have multiplied 8 to the second part of the function also and that the reason you for -3.2 there

Comment: Would you be able to go through it step by step